# get address in variable

Tags: web3js

This line of code returns a new address.
`web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword').then(console.log);`

but how is it possible to get this address in a variable, So it can be used for inserting into database

Comment: `const myAddress = await web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword');` should work

Comment: give give me err. is there any complete code example? `const myAddress = await web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword');
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:613:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)

`

Comment: This is a javascript problem, you need to understand how variables works, how to use promises, and how to call functions with async/await. A solution without async/await is `var myAddress; web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword').then((result) => { myAddress = result; })`. I'd suggest to learn how javascript deals with async functions.

Comment: i have go it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re creating an asynchronous request you can retrieve the response using a callback or a promise

```
web3.personal.newAccount("passphrase").then((accountAddress) => { console.log('New Account Address', accountAddress); })
```

Comment: if i run this code like `var accountAddress;
web3.eth.personal.newAccount("!@superpassword").then((accountAddress) => { console.log('New Account Address', accountAddress); });
console.log("New Address : ", accountAddress);` i get following output `
New Address :  undefined
New Account Address 0x485BF2C4981Bb8a15269164FEf28eb2f57dD2955
` Why do i see undefine here?

Comment: Is there any example for promise too?

Comment: Yes, an example is given in [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount)

Comment: Do you have an example for me to get address in a value using callback or promise? im fairly new